# Remove word(s) if they're longer than 30 characters?

Tags: php

I need to remove words from string, if they're longer than 20 characters. I've tried this but it only adds line breaks.

```
wordwrap($line,30,"",true);
```

Comment: some `preg_replace` regexp could be useful here.

Comment: what about the valid words longer than 30 characters, wont removing them 'break' the contents? there is a local hill called "Taumata­whakatangihanga­koauau­o­tamatea­turi­pukakapiki­maunga­horo­nuku­pokai­whenua­kitanatahu"

Comment: I don't need that hill, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = 'asd qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq weq';

var_dump(preg_replace('~\b\S{5,}\b~', '', $str));
```

The code above removes everything longer than 5 consecutive non-space characters. Replace 5 with 30 and you'll get what you want

Comment: Nice one. What's the difference between var_dump() and echo ?

Comment: @user198989: `var_dump` is for debugging purposes - it shows you the type of a variable, its length, and for non-scalar types like arrays and objects - theirs nested data. So when you develop and want to check what variable contains - **always** use `var_dump`. PS: compare `echo false;` and `var_dump(false);`